# How to work with nested array

Tags: solidity, arrays

Please how do i map addresses to each array

I have parameters of an array inside an array, and i want to map each array to each address, please how do I go about this? thanks

contract SolahParchiThap {

```
address owner = msg.sender;
modifier onlyOwner {require(msg.sender == owner); _;}

mapping(address => uint[]) _players;

// To set and start the game
function setState(address[4] memory players, uint8[4][4] memory parchis) view public onlyOwner returns (string memory){
    
    for (uint i=0; i <= players.length; i++){
        if (players[i] == owner){
            return ("Owner can not be a player");
        } else {
            
        }
    }    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about codes below?

```
contract SolahParchiThap {

    address owner = msg.sender;
    modifier onlyOwner {require(msg.sender == owner); _;}

    mapping(address => uint8[]) _players;

    // To set and start the game
    function setState(address[] memory players, uint8[][] memory parchis) public onlyOwner returns (string memory){
        
        for (uint i=0; i < players.length; i++){
            if (players[i] == owner){
                return ("Owner can not be a player");
            } else {
                _players[players[i]] = parchis[i];
            }
        }

        return ("Succeeded");
    }
}
```

I changed 6 points from your source.

1. Mapping variable's type declaration

- It seems that a mappinng variable `_players` stores (player's addres => player's parchis).
  In your source, mapped value type was declared as array of `uint`, but your function receives array of `uint8`.
  If you want to store recived parchis, mapped value type also should to be declared as array of `uint8`.

2. View option in function's declaration

- Your function may change member variable `_players`.
  So it is not `view` function. It must be removed.

3. Length of Array in function's declaration

- Because there is a loop for each player in your source, I think that length of `players` parameter will be variable.
  So I removed length specifications to each array.

4. Loop condition

- It is wrong that `i <= players.length`.
  It should be `i < players.length`.

5. Add store procedure

- At `else` case of player's address check (in player for-loop), I added a procedure which stores received parchis.
  It is a simple usage of mapping type.

6. Add succeeded return value

- End of your function, add return procedure when succeeded.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It works, thanks, you are awesome...I will keep learning, I see I made little mistakes here and there

Comment: I'm happy too it works well. You can check the answer to close it. :)